# Google Maps Geocoding location not returning town

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have written a function to return the town of any GPS co-ordinates passed to the function but for some reason its not returning the town.  If I alert the town, it shows me the correct town.

**Code:**

```
function getTown(latitude,longitude){

    // Define Geocoding 
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder(); 

    // Using the longitude / latitude get address details
    var latlng  = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude,longitude);

    geocoder.geocode({'latLng': latlng}, function(results, status){

        // If response ok then get details
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {          
            var town = results[1].address_components[1].long_name;

            return town; // Returns Norwich when alerted using the e.g below.
        }           
    });
}
```

**Example:**

```
getTown(52.649334,1.288052);
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be because you are returning town from **inside** a nested function. The call to geocoder.geocode is asynchronous and will return after some time has passed. You could set it to a variable like this:

```
var theTown = null;
function getTown(latitude,longitude){

// Define Geocoding 
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder(); 

// Using the longitude / latitude get address details
var latlng  = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude,longitude);

geocoder.geocode({'latLng': latlng}, function(results, status){

    // If response ok then get details
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {          
        var town = results[1].address_components[1].long_name;

        theTown = town; // Returns Norwich when alerted using the e.g below.
    }           
});
}
```

Comment: This has made no difference??

Comment: If you're expectation is to run `var town = getTown(52.649334,1.288052);` and have town set to **Norwich**, its simply **never** going to happen. The call to `geocoder.geocode` takes time. How much time? It will be different every time you call the method, but probably a few hundred milliseconds as you send a request across the internet to get some data back from Google. You're working with [asynchronous I/O](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asynchronous_I/O), an important concept on your programming quest.

Comment: How come I can alert it instantly and not return it?

Comment: Its not really "instantly", just really fast (~100ms) and definitely not in-band with the function returning. It is making an HTTP request in the background. Open a developer console like Firebug or Chrome developer console and watch the network tab. You'll see the request fire off and come back.

Comment: Hmm I am not sure what to do, can you see any way round the issue or know of another solution?

Comment: What do you want to do with the town name that you get back? I can help you work that out.

Comment: I am developing an instagram feed and wanted to translate the GPS co-ordinates into a readable location.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17471/discussion-between-kale-mcnaney-and-chill-web-designs)